# change background of selected navigation for the next load

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am designing a vertical menu for my website and trying to change the background colour of the navigation item when it is clicked and the page loaded using jQuery.  It changes the background until the pages is not loaded. When the page is loaded, the background change is not present. I am following [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6w0sy8gp/2/). I am designing similar to w3school left navigation menu when an item is clicked, it retains the background change for that li/a/navigation item. How can I properly code to keep the background change for that specific link/a navigation item, for the next load? Here is my code.

```js
$('.widget_nav_plus_widget a').click(function(e) {
    $('.widget_nav_plus_widget a').removeClass('current_page_item');
    $(this).addClass('current_page_item');

});
```

```css
.widget_nav_plus_widget{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.widget_nav_plus_widget ul li {
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
   background-color:#236870;
    margin-left: -30px;
    margin-right: -30px;
    line-height:1.7em;
    }

.widget_nav_plus_widget ul li a{
color:white;
 text-decoration: none;
  display:block;
} 
.widget_nav_plus_widget ul li a:hover{
color:white;
 display:block;  
  text-indent: 1em;
   background-color:#0034a1;
}
.widget_nav_plus_widget ul ul li{
    text-indent: 1em;
     background-color: white;
     color:black;
    margin-top:-10px;
}
.widget_nav_plus_widget ul ul li a{
color:black;
 text-decoration: none;
    display:block;
  } 
.widget_nav_plus_widget ul ul li a:hover{
color:white;
    display:block;
  text-indent: 1em;
      background-color:#4ba668;
   }
.widget_nav_plus_widget ul ul ul li{
    text-indent: 3em;
}   
.widget_nav_plus_widget ul ul ul li:hover{
    text-indent: 3em;
}
.widget_nav_plus_widget ul ul ul li a:hover{
color:white;
    display:block;
  text-indent: 3em;
      background-color:#4ba668;
      
}

.current_page_item{
   background-color:#4ba668;
  color: white;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<aside id="nav_plus_widget-2" class="widget inner-padding widget_nav_plus_widget XXsnipcss_extracted_selector_selectionXX">
  <div class="menu-cpp-main-menu-duplicate-container">
    <ul id="menu-cpp-main-menu-duplicate" class="menu">
      <li id="menu-item-2486" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent menu-item-has-children menu-item-2486">
        <a href="#" tabindex="1" >
          Basics
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
       
          <li id="menu-item-2463" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-2463">
            <a href="#cpp-loops" tabindex="1">
              C++ Loops
            </a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-2464" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-has-children menu-item-2464">
            <a href="#c-functions" tabindex="1">
              C++ Functions
            </a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li id="menu-item-2465" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-2465">
                <a href="#cpp-functions-overloading" tabindex="1">
                  C++ Functions Overloading
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-2466" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-2466">
            <a href="#cpp-structure" tabindex="1">
              C++ Structures
            </a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-2467" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-2467">
            <a href="#cpp-pointers" tabindex="1">
              C++ Pointers
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-2468" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-has-children menu-item-2468">
        <a href="#cpp-object-oriented-programming" tabindex="1">
          C++ Object Oriented Programming
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-2469" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-2469">
            <a href="#c-classses-objects" tabindex="1">
              C++ Classses and Objects
            </a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-2470" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-2470">
            <a href="#cpp-inheritance" tabindex="1">
              C++ Inheritance
            </a>
          </li>
          
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The question / problem is a little unclear. I am not sure what you mean by '*When the page is loaded, the background change is not present.*' Do you mean when you navigate to another back and then back, and the page reloads? What did you expect to happen? Please remember that the change you make with script will not be retained unless you save it someplace.

Comment: Sounds like maybe you need to store the state in a variable or database or some sort.  localstorage might be what you're looking for if you want to do this clientside.

Comment: @Twisty Thank you for your reply. Yes, the above go code is the navigation code. When user clicks on C++ Loops(lets say), I want the background of this navigation  when the loads. Similarly,  if he navigates to another page like C++ pointers, then the background of this navigation should be changed and the C++ Loops should be back to the original colors so the user can on which page navigation page is he..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the LocalStorage, I have made some changes in your JS code.

```
const currentPage = localStorage.getItem("currentPage");
$(`a[href='${currentPage}']`).addClass('current_page_item');

$('.widget_nav_plus_widget a').click(function(e) {
    $('.widget_nav_plus_widget a').removeClass('current_page_item');
    $(this).addClass('current_page_item');
    localStorage.setItem("currentPage", $(this).attr('href'));

});
```